# How to implement different data in each fragment with FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android

In my case, I'm using a fragment to present the different data. The 'pageCreated' parameter is shown quantity fragment will be created (example: 3,4...n) and show it in a ViewPager.

Here is my code.

**Adapter**

```
public class ExercisePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int pageCreated;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param fm
 */
public ExercisePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int pageCreated) {
    super(fm);
    this.pageCreated = pageCreated;
}


/**
 * Return fragment based on the position
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    List<ExerciseListPageFragment> listPageFragment = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCreated; i++) {
        listPageFragment.add(ExerciseListPageFragment.newInstance(i, "ExerciseListPageFragment, Instance " + i));
    }
    return listPageFragment.get(position);
}

/**
 * Return the number of pages
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pageCreated;
}}

**Fragment**

public class ExerciseListPageFragment extends BaseFragment {


/**
 * Returns new instance.
 *
 * @param text
 * @return
 */
public static ExerciseListPageFragment newInstance(int page, String text) {

    // new instance
    ExerciseListPageFragment instance = new ExerciseListPageFragment();

    // sets data to bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("msg", text);
    bundle.putInt("page", page);

    // set data to fragment
    instance.setArguments(bundle);

    return instance;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String msg = getArguments().getString("msg");
    int page = getArguments().getInt("page");

}

/**
 * Create fragment view when paginated.
 *
 * @param inflater
 * @param container
 * @param savedInstanceState
 * @return
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise_list_page, container, false);
}

/**
 * Return the position of page
 *
 * @return
 */
@Override
protected int getLayout() {
    return 0;
}}
```

**Fragment Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Workout"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_exercise"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_text"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And **Activity**

```
private void setupViewPager() {
    //setup viewpager present layout though MyPagerAdapter
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ExercisePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),pageCreate));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    //setup layout dot
    setupUIPageViewController();
}
```

When the 'pageCreated' parameter is passing 3 or 4, the same fragment will be created. So, I want to present different data in 3, 4 fragments through RecyclerView. How can I do it?

The page 1:
[image]

The page 2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To show different data in each Fragment of a view pager add list in constructor of Fragment and with data in list show and modify your views on each Fragment

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
List<String> stringList;
public static OneFragment newInstance(int position, List<String> TITLES) {
    OneFragment f = new OneFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("mPosition", position);
    args.putStringArrayList("TITLES", (ArrayList<String>) TITLES);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPosition = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("mPosition") : 0;
    this.stringList = getArguments().getStringArrayList("TITLES");
 }
}
//DO your desired stuff with stringList
```